# How to do a special difference in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list in Python containing

```
['A,1,2,2,4','B,1,3,2,4','C,1,2,3,4']
```

How do I get an output of:

```
['A,2,2']
['B,3,2']
['C,2,3']
```

However, the same line(s) of code should be able to do the same with a variable list, such as:

```
['A,4,2,1,5',
 'B,3,2,1,5',
 'C,6,2,3,5',
 'D,1,2,3,5']
```

output of:

```
['A,4,1',
 'B,3,1',
 'C,6,3',
 'D,1,3']
```

Comment: Are you sure that the input list is not like this `[['A', '1', '2', '2', '4'], ['B', '1', '3', '2', '4'], ['C', '1', '2', '3', '4']]`?

Comment: Split each element into an array, get the elements you want, join it back into a string, and make an array of the results.

Comment: I haven't found anything solid to try yet. I have tried thefourtheye's method with no luck. This is due to how it relies on the 0th, 2nd, and 3rd item to be different. My lists will be dynamic, however the lengths will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One neat way to get the result is to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with the string split based on `,`, like this

```
>>> my_list = ['A,1,2,2,4','B,1,3,2,4','C,1,2,3,4']
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [",".join(itemgetter(0, 2, 3)(items.split(","))) for items in my_list]
['A,2,2', 'B,3,2', 'C,2,3']
```

Or form a generator expression which gives strings by splitting based on `,` and then pick only the elements at index 0, 2 and 3 and join all them with `,` like this

```
>>> [",".join([j[0], j[2], j[3]]) for j in (d.split(",") for d in my_list)]
['A,2,2', 'B,3,2', 'C,2,3']
```

Here, `(d.split(",") for d in my_list)` is called a *generator expression* which gives a new list of strings split based on `,`, on every iteration.

Comment: No dice, I should have specified that my data won't always be the 0th, 2nd, and 3rd entries that will be different.

Comment: @mbrockman1 Can you give an example? Anyway, you can always create an `itemgetter` object with new indexes and use them with lists

Comment: So, the example I was giving is a simple example to my complex bioinformatics problem that I am trying to solve. I am doing analytics on amino acids that make up proteins of a species of bacteria. So A,B,C would be a protein, and the numbers would be the amino acid frequency. So the above example may be good for 1 protein comparison, however the next comparison, which python would do in a loop, may loo like    [['A', '5', '3', '1', '7'], ['B', '1', '3', '1', '4'], ['C', '1', '3', '1', '4']]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the motivation here is / how generic you need the code to be. This works for your specific instance:

```
[[seq[:2] + seq[4:7]] for seq in ['A,1,2,2,4','B,1,3,2,4','C,1,2,3,4']]
```

This essentially maps taking the substrings you want onto every string in your array. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve it's hard to say more.

Comment: Sorry for the generality, I need this programming method to be dynamic, meaning that the list entries will need to be dynamic, however the length of each entry will be the exact same. And thank you for the quick response!

Comment: What do you mean by dynamique. the two in the middle whatever the size of the list ?

Comment: It may not always be the 2nd and 3rd points that are different in list